# Why doesn't Moose role application with method modifiers work in my code?

Tags: perl, moose, role, method-modifier

I have a Role and several classes that mix-in the role. The Role class loads all of the implementing classes so that anything that imports Blah can use them without typing a lot of 'use' lines.

```
package Blah;
use Moose::Role;

use Blah::A;
use Blah::B;
(etc...)

requires '...';
requires 'foo';
around 'foo' => sub { ... }
```

A typical Blah subclass:

```
package Blah::A;
use Moose;
with 'Blah';

sub foo { ... }

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

Since every subclass 'foo' method starts with the same bits of code, the role also implements these via a method modifier.

Problem is: Moose doesn't apply the method modifier to any of the Blah::* classes. This happens even if I remove the make_immutable call for the classes. I thought role application was done entirely at runtime, and so even though the Blah::* classes are loaded before Blah, the modifier should still be applied?

I'm looking for a fix, or an alternate way of doing things. At the moment Blah is essentially an abstract base class except for the method modifier, which is why I used roles to begin with - but maybe a class hierarchy would be better? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call order is a little odd -- why are you `use`ing Blah::A from within the role that is then applied to Blah::A?

I would suggest pulling out these `use` lines and moving them to where they are actually needed (in the caller(s)). Get the code working first, and after that, if you have lots of `use` lines cluttering things up everywhere, you could move them off into an Includes file.

But no, in answer to your assumption -- role application is *not* done at runtime, but at whatever time the `with` line is encountered. If you `use` a module at compile-time, then that file is compiled immediately, and the `with` line executed (which then forces the role to be compiled, and then it is run).  You can of course apply a role at runtime as well (e.g. see apply_all_roles in [Moose::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Util)), but that is not what is happening here.

Comment: Accepted, thanks. The use lines are annoying, but I guess I'll write a factory module for them instead of overloading the role module :)

Comment: @rjh: yes, you're just loading those target modules too soon, before the role has had a chance to finish building itself and get applied to them.

Answer (score -1):

I think you simply misunderstand the difference between file-inclusion, and role composition.

Under the hood, `use` statements simply call `require` and then the inferred Package's `import()` statement and wrap all of this in a `BEGIN {}` block.

It doesn't install the functions as meta-class methods with Class::MOP (CMOP). I'm not sure what the difference is between a declared method and an imported one, or how CMOP tells the difference but this works only because of the call to `add_method`. I'd ask for more information from irc.perl.org/#moose, but I'm banned. Hopefully this example will tell you what you need, or give you more information to formulate a better question.

```
package Class;
use Moose;
use Carp qw(carp);

### You have to add the method onto the class.
Class->meta->add_method( 'carp' => \&carp );

around 'carp' => sub { warn "this won't trigger" };

package main;

my $c = Class->new;
$c->carp('foo');
```

If possible I'd rewrite those packages your `use`ing into Moose friendly Roles, then just have the current role call the new roles using the `with` statement. Roles will handle method modifiers around other role-provided methods.

Comment: Evan I think you have entirely missed the question here. He *is* using a Role (Blah is a Moose::Role). His issues are related to the circular use statements (use-ing a Class that does the Role you're currently defining is bad M'kay?) and timing (composition as ether points out happens when the `with` is seen, and can cause issues). 

I can't see how your example here has anything to do with the question since he's neither using imports, nor shown an example of entirely overriding a method with an `around` modifier like you've done here. 

Rjh is free to come into #moose for more information.

Comment: Going up to bat, I'm going to assume the issue is *specific* to the `use` cases because that code will work without it (remove the use's and requires) instantiate `Blah::A`, and I believe the 'around' will work. Maybe I tried to infer to much.